# TCP need to discard info on the buffer or make it faster

Tags: c++, mobile, tcp, tcpserver

I am making a 3d application that works with the data of the accelerometer and gyroscope of the mobile. The problem is that the mobile sends data faster than the computer reads. The application increasingly makes the movements of the mobile with more delay as time passes. For example, at the beginning 2~3s is faithful to what the mobile does in reality, but over 10s it is making the movements that I did 6 seconds  before.

I understand that it is reading data from the beginning buffer while the front of the most current data grows and never reaches it. I think the problem is how I read the data that comes to me.

Here is an example code that is implemented in the application. What could I do?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        int opt = 1;
        int addrlen = sizeof(address);
        char buffer[1024] = {0};

        const char *ACK = "ACKDAT\n";

        std::string data;

        socklen_t len;
        char *error;

        if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
        {
                perror("socket failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

   
        if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, sizeof(opt)))
        {
                perror("setsockopt");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

        if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
        {
                perror("bind failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
        {
                perror("listen");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fcntl(new_socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

        while(true){
                valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
                for(int i = 0;i < 1024 ; i++){
                        if(buffer[i]!=0){
                                data = data + buffer[i];
                        }
                        buffer[i]=0;
                }
                if(!data.empty()){
                        //remove /n from data
                        data.erase(std::remove(data.begin(), data.end(), '\n'), data.end());
                        std::cout<<"#"<<data<<"#"<<std::endl;
                        send(new_socket , ACK , strlen(ACK) , 0 );
                }
                data.clear();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is C++, please don't tag other unrelated languages.

Comment: As for possible optimization, why do you need to copy the data from `buffer`? And why do it in your own loop rather than let the `std::string` class handle it for you? And `read` returns the length of the data it have received (or an error, or connection closed, neither which you check for!) so you don't need to check for and set the array to zero.

Comment: And don't use `std::endl`, as that will not only print a newline but also force a flush of the buffered output which slows down the writing to the terminal. Just print a plain `'\n'` and then let the output be flushed as and when needed. There's also no need to clear `data` afterward (assuming you fix the copying), and if there's only a single newline at the end of the string you don't need `erase` or `remove`. And don't call `stlen` repeatedly with a string of a known size.

Comment: On another note, while TCP may be reliable but it's also a *streaming* protocol, with no message boundaries. All the data that flows through the connection is just a stream of bytes. That means a single call to `read` may not give you a whole "message", or it may give you *more* than a whole message (including partial messages). Therefore your code may become out of sync, and return false acknowledge messages.

Comment: Oh by the way, the socket options (like `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT`) are *not* bit flags. So you can't use bitwise OR to set both flags. Also note that these two options do very different things despite their similar name. You don't really need `SO_REUSEPORT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Sam Varshavchik's suggestion of using a thread is good, there's another option.

You already set your socket to non-blocking with `fcntl(new_socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`. So, at each loop you should read everything there is to read and send everything there is to send. If you don't tie one-to-one the reading and writing, both sides will be able to catch up.

The main hint that you need to fix this is that you don't use the `read` return value, `valread`. Your code should look like:

```
while(true){ // main loop

...

valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
while(valread > 0)
{
    // deal with the read values.
    // deal with receiving more than one packet per iteration
}
// send code done a single time per loop.
```

There still plenty of architecture you need to have a clean resilient main loop that sends and receives, but I hope that points you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all reading from the socket done in a separate `std::thread`, that does nothing but read from the socket and save the data in your program's internal buffer. Your existing program reads from the internal buffer, rather than a socket, whenever it is capable of doing so.

If the internal buffer is full you'll have to figure out what to do about it, probably discard unwanted data. Perhaps stash a copy of the most recent received record, in a safe place, and put it into the buffer when things get unclogged. The dedicated execution thread will likely need to do some minimal processing, to parse the raw data from the socket into some meaningful, logical form. It's unlikely that you can simply throw away random parts of the raw data stream from the socket. It will need to be logically parsed, in some form or fashion that's particular to your application, so this can be done in a meaningful way.

You will need to implement your application's buffer in a thread-safe manner, so that it can be simultaneously accessed by multiple execution threads. If you're not familiar with multi-threaded programming in C++, you will find more information in your C++ textbook, on this topic.